# Concurrency: How do you approach the design and debug the implementation?

Tags: design, debugging, parallelism, concurrency

I've been developing concurrent systems for several years now, and I have a pretty good grasp on the subject despite my lack of formal training (i.e. no degree).  There's a few new languages that have become popular to at least talk about lately that are designed to make concurrency easier such as Erlang and Go.  It appears that their approach to concurrency echoes my own experience as to how to make systems scalable and take advantage of multiple cores/processors/machines.

However, I find that there are very few tools to help visualize what you intend to do, and verify that you are at least close to your original vision.  Debugging concurrent code can be a nightmare with languages that are not designed for concurrency (like C/C++, C#, Java, etc.).  In particular, it can be near impossible to recreate conditions that happen readily on one system in your development environment.

So, what are your approaches to designing a system to deal with concurrency and parallel processing?  Examples:

- How do you figure out what can be made concurrent vs. what has to be sequential?
- How do you reproduce error conditions and view what is happening as the application executes?
- How do you visualize the interactions between the different concurrent parts of the application?

I have my own answers for some of these, but I'd also like to learn a bit more.

**Edit**

So far we have a lot of good input.  Many of the articles linked to are very good, and I've already read some of them.

My personal experience with concurrent programming leads me to believe you need a different mindset than you do with sequential programming.  The mental divide is probably as wide as the difference between object oriented programming and procedural programming.  I'd like this set of questions to focus more on the thought processes necessary (i.e. theory) to systematically approach the answers.  When providing more concrete answers, it helps to provide an example--something you went through personally.

**Goal for the Bounty**

Don't tell me what I should do.  I already have that under control.  Tell me what you do.  Tell me how *you* solve these problems.

Comment: THis is a good question - a lot of possible depth. I've also gotten some good experience with multi-threaded applications in Java, but would like to learn more.

Comment: So far, we have a few good answers.  Anyone want to venture a stab at what you wish you had to help you in this area?

Comment: TotalView Debugger for concurrent coding is a pretty useful tool, takes a bit of a learning curve though -- http://www.totalviewtech.com/products/totalview.html

Comment: Maybe logging could help you with two last questions.

Comment: What I'm looking for are people's processes.  These are areas where the tools I've been using are inadequate, but can get the job done.  I'm less concerned about quoting someone else's article and more concerned about methodology here.

Comment: Have you looked at the Reactive Programming paradigm? While the learning curve is steep and you are forced to use a bunch of verbose operators, the pro is absolute clarity

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I've been developing concurrent
>   systems for several years now, and I
>   have a pretty good grasp on the
>   subject despite my lack of formal
>   training (i.e. no degree).

Many of best programmers I know didn't finish the University. 
As for me I studied Philosophy.

> C/C++, C#, Java, etc.). In particular,
>   it can be near impossible to recreate
>   conditions that happen readily on one
>   system in your development
>   environment.

yes

> How do you figure out what can be made concurrent vs. what has to be
>   sequential?

we usually start with a 1000 miles high metaphor to clarify our architecture to ourselves (firstly) and to others (secondly).

When we faced that problem, we always found a way to limiting the visibility of concurrent objects to non concurrent ones.

Lately I discovered Actors in scala and I saw that my old solutions were a kind of "miniactors", much less powerful than scala ones. So my suggestion is to start from there.

Another suggestion is to skip as many problems as possible: for example we use centralised cache (terracotta) instead of keeping maps in memory, using inner class callbacks instead of synchronised methods, sending messages instead of writing shared memory etc.

With scala it's all much easier anyway.

> How do you reproduce error conditions and view what is happening
>   as the application executes?

No real answer here. We have some unit test for concurrency and we have a load test suite to stress the application as much as we can.

> How do you visualize the interactions between the different
>   concurrent parts of the application?

Again no real answer: we design our Metaphor on the whiteboard and we try to make sure there are no conflicts on the architectural side.

For Arch here I mean the Neal Ford's definition: Sw Architecture is everything that will be very hard to change later.

> programming leads me to believe you
>   need a different mindset than you do
>   with sequential programming.

Maybe but for me it's simply impossible to think in a parallel way, so better design our software in a way that doesn't require parallel thinking and with clear guardrails to avoid crashes between concurrency lanes.

Answer (score 6):

To me is all about the data. Break your data right, and parallel processing is easy. All the problems with retention, deadlocks, and so go away.

I do know that this is not the only way to parallelize, but for me is far the most useful.

To illustrate, a (not-so-quick) story:

I did work on a big financial (stock-market control) system on 2007 through 2009, and the processing volume of the data was very big. To illustrate, all calculations done to 1 single account of a client took about 1~3 seconds on their average workstation, and there were more than 30k accounts. Every night, closing the system was a big pain to the users (usually more than 6 hours processing, without any error-margin for them).

Studying the problem further revealed that we could paralelize the calculations among several computers, but we would still have a huge bottleneck on the old database server (an SQL 2000 server emulating SQL 6.5).

It was pretty clear that our minimum processing packet was the calculation of single account, and the major bottleneck were the database server retention (we could see on the "sp_who"s several connections waiting to do the same processing). So the parallel process went like this:

1) One single producer, responsible for either reading the database or writing on it, sequentially. No concurrency allowed here. The producer prepared a queue of jobs, for the consumers. The database belonged solely to this producer.

2) Several consumers, on several machines. Each one of the consumers received a whole packet of data, from the queue, ready to calculate. Each deqeue operation is synchronized.

3) After the calculation, each consumer sent back the data to an in-memory synchonized queue to the producer, in order to persist the data.

There were several check-points, several mechanisms to assure the transactions were correctly saved (none was left behind), but the whole work was worth of it. In the end, the calculations spread among 10 computers (plus the producer/queue computer) took down the closing time os the whole system to 15 minutes.

Just taking away the retention problems caused by the poor concurrency management SQL 6.5 had gave us a big advantage. The rest was pretty much linear, each new computer added to the "grid" made the processing time down, until we reached the "maximum efficiency" of the sequential read/write operations on the database.

Answer (score 2):

Working in multi-threading environment is tough and needs the coding discipline. You need to follow the proper guideline for taking the lock, releasing lock, accessing global variables etc.

Let me try to answer your question one bye one

```
* How do you figure out what can be made concurrent vs. what has to be sequential?
```

Use concurrency for

1) Polling :- need a thread to continuously poll something or send the update on regular basis. (Concepts like heart-bits, which send some data on regular interval to central server to say that I am alive.)

2) The operations which has heavy i/o could be made parallel. The best example is logger. The logger thread could be a separate thread.

3) Similar tasks on different data. If there is some task which happens on different data but very similar in nature, different threads can do this. Best example will be server requests.

And off course many others like this depending on application.

```
* How do you reproduce error conditions and view what is happening as the application executes?
```

Using logs and debug prints in the logs. Try to log also the thread id so you can see what is happening in each thread.
One way to produce error condition is to put the deliberate delay (in debug code) in the places where you think the issue is happening, and forcefully stopping that thread. Similar things can be done in debuggers too, but I haven't done it so far.

```
* How do you visualize the interactions between the different concurrent parts of the application?
```

Put the logs in your locks, so that you will know who is locking what and when, and who has tried for lock. As I said earlier try to put thread id in the log to understand what is going on in each thread.

This is just my piece of advice which is of around 3 years of working on multithread application, and hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

- How do you figure out what can be made concurrent vs. what has to be sequential?

I would question first whether the application (or component) will actually see a benefit from concurrent processing, or in layman's terms -- where is the bottleneck?  Concurrency will obviously not always provide a benefit for the investment it takes to make it work. If it looks like a candidate, then I would work bottom up -- trying to find the largest operation or set of operations that can do its work effectively in isolation -- I don't want to spin up threads for insignificant, cost-ineffective operations -- I'm looking for [Actors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model).

Working with Erlang I've come to absolutely love the concept of using asynchronous message passing and the actor model for concurrency -- it's intuitive, effective, and clean.

Off of [Understanding Actor Concurrency](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-actor-concurrency1.html?page=2)

> The actor model consists of a few key principles:
>
> - No shared state
> - Lightweight processes
> - Asynchronous message-passing
> - Mailboxes to buffer incoming messages
> - Mailbox processing with pattern matching
>
> An actor is a process that executes a function. Here a process is a lightweight user-space thread (not to be confused with a typical heavyweight operating-system process). Actors never share state and thus never need to compete for locks for access to shared data. Instead, actors share data by sending messages that are immutable. Immutable data cannot be modified, so reads do not require a lock.

The Erlang concurrency model is easier to understand and debug than locking and shared data.  The way in which your logic is isolated makes is easy to do testing of components by passing them messages.

Working with concurrent systems this is pretty much how my design worked anyway in any language -- a queue that multiple threads would pull data from, perform a simple operation and repeat or push back onto the queue.  Erlang is just enforcing immutable data structures to prevent side-effects and reducing the cost and complexity of creating new threads.

This model is not Erlang exclusive, even within the Java and .NET world there exists ways to create this -- I would look at the [Concurrency and Coordination Runtime (CCR)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb648752.aspx) and [Relang](http://code.google.com/p/retlang/) (there is also Jetlang for Java).

- How do you reproduce error conditions and view what is happening as the application executes?

In my experience, the only thing I can have done is given a commitment to tracing / logging everything.  Every process / thread needs to have an identifier and each new unit of work needs to have a correlation id.  You need to be able to look through your logs and trace exactly what was being processed and when -- there's no magic I've seen to eliminate this.

- How do you visualize the interactions between the different concurrent parts of the application?

See above, it's ugly but it works.  The only other thing I do is to use UML sequence diagrams -- of course this is during design time -- but you can use them to verify that your components are speaking the way that you want them too.

Answer (score 1):

-- My answers are MS/Visual Studio specific --

> How do you figure out what can be made concurrent vs. what has to be sequential?

That's going to take domain knowledge, there's not going to be any blanket statement here to cover it.

> How do you reproduce error conditions and view what is happening as the application executes?

Lots of logging, being able to turn logging on/off/up in production applications in order to catch it in production.  [VS2010 Intellitrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx) is supposed to be able to help with this, but I haven't used it yet.

> How do you visualize the interactions between the different concurrent parts of the application?

I don't have a good answer to this, would love to see one.

Comment: Logging will change how the code executes and thus may lead to the error you are after not showing up.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with your statement that C is not designed for concurrency. C is designed for general systems programming and enjoys a tenacity for pointing out critical decisions to be made, and will continue to do so for years to come. This is true even when the best decision might be not to use C. Additionally, concurrency in C is only as difficult as your design is complex.

I try, to the best of my ability, to implement locks with the idea that eventually, truly *practical* lock free programming might become a reality for me. By locking, I don't mean mutual exclusion, I simply mean a process that implements safe concurrency without the need for arbitration. By practical, I mean something that is easier to port than it was to implement. I have very little formal CS training as well, but I suppose that I'm permitted to wish :)

Following that, most bugs that I encounter become relatively shallow, or so completely mind boggling that I retreat to a pub. The pub becomes an attractive option only when profiling a program slows it down sufficiently to expose additional races that aren't related to what I'm trying to find.

As others have pointed out, the problem that you describe is extremely domain specific. I just try, with the best of my ability to avoid any case that might require arbitration (outside of my process) whenever possible. If that looks like it might be a regal pain, I re-evaluate the option of giving multiple threads or processes concurrent and unserialized access to something.

Then again, throw 'distributed' in there and arbitration becomes a must. Do you have a specific example?

Comment: To clarify my statement, C was not designed specifically for and around concurrency.  This is in contrast to languages like Go, Erlang, and Scala which were designed explicitly with concurrency in mind.  I was not intending to say you can't do concurrency with C.

Answer (score 1):

> How do you reproduce error conditions and view what is happening as the application executes?
>
> How do you visualize the interactions between the different concurrent parts of the application?

Based on my experience, the answer to  these two aspects are as follows:

**[Distributed tracing](http://zipkin.io)**

Distributed tracing is technology that captures timing data for each individual concurrent component of your system, and presents it to you in graphical format. Representations of concurrent executions are always interleaved, allowing you to see what is running in parallel and what is not.

Distributed tracing owes its origins in (of course) distributed systems, which are by definition asynchronous and highly concurrent. A distributed system with distributed tracing enables people to:

a) identify important bottlenecks, 
b) obtain a visual representation of ideal 'runs' of your application, and 
c) provide visibility into what concurrent behaviour is being executed,
d) obtain timing data which can be used to assess differences between changes in your system (extremely important if you have strong SLAs).

The consequences of distributed tracing, however, are:

1. It adds overhead to all of your concurrent processes, as it translates into more code to execute and submit potentially over a network. In some cases, this overhead is highly significant - even Google only uses their tracing system Dapper on a small subset of all requests so as not to ruin user experience.
2. Many different tools exist, not all of which are interoperable with each other. This is somewhat ameliorated by standards like OpenTracing, but not wholly solved.
3. It tells you *nothing* about shared resources and their current status. You may be able to guess, based on the application code and what the graph you see is showing you, but it's not a useful tool in this regard.
4. Current tools assume you have memory and storage to spare. Hosting a timeseries server may not be cheap, depending on your constraints.

**[Error tracking software](https://sentry.io/welcome/)**

I link to Sentry above primarily because it is the most widely used tool out there, and for good reason - error tracking software like Sentry hijack runtime execution to simultaneously forward a stack trace of the errors encountered to a central server.

The net benefit of such dedicated software in concurrent code:

1. **Duplicate errors are not duplicated**. In other words, if one or more concurrent systems encounter the same exception, Sentry will *increment* an incident report, but not submit two copies of the incident.

This means you can figure out which concurrent system is experiencing which kind of error without having to go through countless simultaneous error reports. If you've ever suffered email spam from a distributed system, you know what hell feels like.

You can even 'tag' different aspects of your concurrent system (though this assumes you don't have work interleaved over exactly one thread, which technically isn't concurrent anyway since the thread is simply jumping between tasks efficiently but must still process event handlers to completion) and see a breakdown of the errors by tag.

2. You can modify this error handling software to provide extra details with your runtime exceptions. What open resources did the process have? Is there a shared resource that this process was holding? Which user experienced this issue?

This, in addition to meticulous stack traces (and source maps, if you have to provide a minified version of your files), makes it easy to determine what's going wrong a large portion of the time.

3. (Sentry-specific) You can have a separate Sentry reporting dashboard for test runs of the system, allowing you to catch errors in testing.

The disadvantages of such software include:

1. Like everything, they add bulk. You may not want such a system on embedded hardware, for instance. I highly recommend doing a trial run of such software, comparing a simple execution with and without it sampled over a few hundred runs on an idle machine.
2. Not all languages are equally supported, as many of these systems rely on implicitly catching an exception and not all languages feature robust exceptions. That being said, there are clients for a great deal of systems.
3. They may be raised as a security risk, as many of these systems are essentially closed-source. In such cases, do your due diligence in researching them, or, if preferred, roll your own.
4. They might not always give you the information you need. This is a risk with all attempts to add visibility.
5. Most of these services were designed for highly concurrent web applications, so not every tool may be perfect for your use case.

*In sum*: having visibility is the most crucial part of any concurrent system. The two methods I describe above, in conjunction with dedicated dashboards about hardware and data to get a holidtic picture of the system at any given timepoint, are widely used across the industry precisely to address that aspect.

**Some additional suggestions**

I've spent more time than I care for fixing code by people who tried to solve concurrent problems in terrible ways. Each time, I have found cases where the following things could greatly improve developer experience (which is just as important as user experience):

- **Rely on types**. Typing exists to validate your code, and can be used at runtime as an extra guard. Where typing doesn't exist, rely on assertions and a suitable error handler to catch errors. Concurrent code *requires* defensive code, and types serve as the best kind of validation available.

  - **Test links between code components**, not just the component itself. Do not confuse this with a full-blown integration test - that tests every link between every component, and even then it only looks for a global validation of the final state. This is a terrible way to catch errors.

A good *link test* checks to see if, when one component talks to another component *in isolation*, the message received and the message sent are the same aa you expect. If you have two or more components relying on a shared service to communicate, spin them all up, have them exchange messages via the central service, and see if they're all getting what you expect in the end.

Breaking up tests involving a lot of components into a test of the components themselves and a test of how each of the components communicate as well gives you increased confidence in the validity of your code. Having such a rigorous body of tests allows you to enforce contracts between services as well as catch unexpected errors that occur when they're running at once.

- **Use the right algorithms to validate your application state.** I'm talking about simple things, such as when you have a master process waiting for all of its workers to finish a task and only want to move to the next step if all the workers are fully done - this is an example of detecting global termination, for which known methodologies such as Safra's algorithm exist.

Some of these tools come bundled with languages - Rust, for instance, guarantees your code will have no race conditions at compile-time, while Go features an inbuilt deadlock detector that also runs at compile-time. If you can catch issues before they hit production, it is always a win.

A general rule of thumb: **design for failure in concurrent systems**. Anticipate that common services will crash or break. This goes even for code that isn't distributed across machines - concurrent code on a single machine can rely on external dependencies (such as a shared log file, a Redis server, a damn MySQL server) that could disappear or be removed at any time.

The best way to do this is to validate the application state from time to time - have health checks for each service, and make sure consumers of that service are notified of bad health. Modern container tools like Docker do this quite well, and should be made use of to sandbox things.

> How do you figure out what can be made concurrent and what can be made sequential?

One of the biggest lessons I've learned working on a highly concurrent system is this: *you can never have enough metrics*. Metrics should drive absolutely everything in your application - you are not an engineer if you aren't measuring everything.

Without metrics, you cannot do a few very important things:

1. Assess the difference made by changes to the system. If you don't know if tuning knob A made metric B go up and metric C go down, you don't know how to fix your system when people push unexpectedly malignant code on your system (and they will push code to your system).
2. Understand what you need to do next to improve things. Until you know applications are running low on memory, you can't discern whether you should get more memory or buy more disk for your servers.

Metrics are so crucial and essential that I have made it a conscious effort to plan what I want to measure before I even think about what a system will require. In fact, metrics are so crucial that I believe *they* are the right answer to this question: you only know what can be made sequential or concurrent when you *measure* what the bits in your program are doing. Proper design uses numbers, not guesswork.

That being said, there are certainly a few rules of thumb:

1. Sequential implies dependence. Two processes should be sequential if one is dependent on the other in some fashion. Processes with no dependencies should be concurrent. However, plan a way to handle failure up stream that doesn't prevent processes downstream from waiting indefinitely.
2. Never mix an I/O bound task with a CPU-bound task on the same core. Don't (for example) write a web crawler that launches ten concurrent requests in the same thread, scrapes them as soon as they come in, and expect to scale to five hundred - I/O requests go to a queue in parallel, but the CPU will still go through them serially. (This single-threaded event driven model is a popular one, but it is limited because of this aspect - rather than understand this, people simply wring their hands and say Node doesn't scale, to give you an example).

A single thread can do a lot of I/O work. But in order to fully use your hardware's concurrency, use threadpools that together occupy all cores. In the example above, launching five Python processes (each of which can use a core on a six-core machine) just for CPU work and a sixth Python thread just for I/O work will scale much faster than you think.

The only way to take advantage of CPU concurrency is through a dedicated threadpool. A single thread is often good enough for a lot of I/O bound work. This is why event-driven web servers like Nginx scale better (they do purely I/O bound work) than Apache (which conflates I/O bound work with something requiring CPU and launches a process per request), but why using Node to perform tens of thousands of GPU calculations received in parallel is a *terrible* idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for the verification process, when designing a large concurrent system - I tend to test the model using [LTSA - Labelled Transition System Analyser](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/ltsa/).  It was developed by my old tutor, who is something of a veteran in the concurrency field and is Head of Computing at Imperial now.

As far as working out what can and cannot be concurrent, there are static analysers that could show that up I believe, though I tend to just draw scheduling diagrams for critical sections, the same as you would for project management.  Then identify sections that perform the same operation repetitively.  A quick-route is just to find loops, as they tend to be the areas that benefit from parallel processing.

Answer (score 0):

> **How do you figure out what can be made concurrent vs. what has to be sequential?**

Pretty much every thing you write can take advantage of concurrency especially the "devide an conquer" use case. A much better question is what *should be concurrent?*

Joseph Albahari's [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) list five common uses.

> Multithreading has many uses; here are
>   the most common:
>
> **Maintaining a responsive user interface**
>
> By running time-consuming
>   tasks on a parallel “worker” thread,
>   the main UI thread is free to continue
>   processing keyboard and mouse events.
>
> **Making efficient use of an otherwise blocked CPU**
>
> Multithreading is useful when a thread
>   is awaiting a response from another
>   computer or piece of hardware. While
>   one thread is blocked while performing
>   the task, other threads can take
>   advantage of the otherwise unburdened
>   computer.
>
> **Parallel programming**
>
> Code that performs intensive
>   calculations can execute faster on
>   multicore or multiprocessor computers
>   if the workload is shared among
>   multiple threads in a
>   “divide-and-conquer” strategy (see
>   Part 5).
>
> **Speculative execution**
>
> On multicore machines, you can
>   sometimes improve performance by
>   predicting something that might need
>   to be done, and then doing it ahead of
>   time. LINQPad uses this technique to
>   speed up the creation of new queries.
>   A variation is to run a number of
>   different algorithms in parallel that
>   all solve the same task. Whichever one
>   finishes first “wins”—this is
>   effective when you can’t know ahead of
>   time which algorithm will execute
>   fastest.
>
> **Allowing requests to be processed simultaneously**
>
> On a server, client requests can
>   arrive concurrently and so need to be
>   handled in parallel (the .NET
>   Framework creates threads for this
>   automatically if you use ASP.NET, WCF,
>   Web Services, or Remoting). This can
>   also be useful on a client (e.g.,
>   handling peer-to-peer networking—or
>   even multiple requests from the user).

If you're not trying to do one of the above you'd probably better think real hard about it.

> **How do you reproduce error conditions and view what is happening as the application executes?**

If you're using .NET and you've written use cases you can use [CHESS](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/CHESS/) which can recreate specific thread interleaving conditions which enables you to test your fix.

> **How do you visualize the interactions between the different concurrent parts of the application?**

It depends on the context. For worker scenarios I think of a manager-subordinate. Manger tells the subordinate to do something and waits for status updates.

For concurrent unrelated tasks I think of elevators or cars in separate lanes of traffic.

For synchronization I sometimes think of traffic lights or turn-styles.

Also if you're using C# 4.0 you might want to take a look at the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

My answer for this questions are:

- How do you figure out what can be
  made concurrent vs. what has to be
  sequential?

First i need to know why should i use concurrency, because i have find out that people gets exited with the idea behind concurrency but not always think about the problem they are trying to solve.

If you have to simulate a real life situation like queues, workflows, etc, you most likely will need to use a concurrent approach.

Now that i know that i should use it, its time to analyze the trade off, if you have lots of proccesses, you may think about communication overhead, but if you have to new, may end up with no concurrent solution ( reanalize problem if so.)

- How do you reproduce error conditions
  and view what is happening as the
  application executes?

I'm no expert on this matter but i think that for concurrent systems this is not the correct approach. A theoretical approach should be choosen, looking for  the 4 deadlock requirements on critical areas:

1. Non preemptiveness
2. Hold and wait
3. Motual exclusion
4. Circular chain

   - How do you visualize the interactions
     between the different concurrent
     parts of the application?

I try to first identify who are the participants in the interactions, then how do they communicate and with whom. Finally, graphs and interaction diagrams help me visualize. My good old whiteboard can not be beaten by any other kind of media.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be blunt.  I adore tools.  I use lots of tools.
My first step is to lay out the intended paths for flow of state.  My next step is to try and figure out if it's worth it, or if the required flow of information will render the code serial too often.  Then, I'll try and draft some simple models.  These can range from a stack of crude toothpick sculptures to some simple similar examples in python.  Next, I look through a couple of my favorite books, like the little book of semaphores, and see if someone's already come up with a better solution to my problem.

Then I start coding.
Just kidding.  A bit more research first.  I like to sit down with a fellow hacker, and walk through an expected execution of the program at a high level.  If questions come up, we step to a lower level.  It's important to find out if someone else can understand your solution well enough to maintain it.

Finally, I start coding.  I try to keep it very simple first.  Just the code path, nothing fancy.  Move as little state as possible.  Avoid writes.  Avoid reads that may conflict with writes.  Avoid, above all else, writes that may conflict with writes.  It's very easy to find that you have a positively toxic number of these, and that your beautiful solution is suddenly little more than a cache-thrashing serial approach.

A good rule is to use frameworks where-ever you can.  If you're writing basic threading components yourself, like good synchronized data structures, or god-forbid, actual synchro-primitives, you are almost certainly going to blow your whole leg off.

Finally, tools.  Debugging is very hard.  I use valgrind\callgrind on linux in conjunction with PIN, and parallel studios on windows.  Do not try and debug this stuff by hand.  You probably can.  But you'll probably wish you hadn't.  Ten hours mastering some powerful tools, and some good models will save you hundreds of hours later.

Above all else, work incrementally.  Work carefully.  Do not write concurrent code when tired.  Do not write it while hungry.  In fact, if you can avoid it, simply do not write it.  Concurrency is hard, and I have found that many apps that list it as a feature often ship with it as their only feature.

In summary:
Begin:
Think
Talk
Test
Write simply
Read
Test
Write
Debug
GOTO Begin